# Java regular expression for HBase scan filter not working

Tags: java, regex, hbase

Problem : Regular expression not working as expected for HBase scan filter.
Although this RegEx passes without any error it doesn't return filtered rows only.

Background :
We are storing our data in HBase as string (I know it should have been in Avro but need to work with this now.)

Our HBase column DataRows look something like below, pipe is used as delimiter.

NAME|10000081|10000102|13513|10102026|GENDER|ID
NAME|10000081|10000101|13513|10102026|GENDER|ID
NAME|10000081|10000103|13513|10102026|GENDER|ID
NAME|10000082|10000104|13515|10102026|GENDER|ID
NAME|10000082|10000104|13516|10102026|GENDER|ID

I am writing a RegEx filter for the HBase scanner which will scan these rows.

My RegEx string looks like this :

```
^NAME\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*$
```

This is input for HBase QualifierFilter, e.g

```
Filter qfilter = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new RegexStringComparator(regexString.toString()));
```

In above example for regex string (I want to filter only Name=RECKO and 3rd col = 10000101).
It returns all rows.

Regex String =   `^NAME\\|.*\\|10000101\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*$`

What is wrong with my regular expression? Any pointers/suggestions are appreciated very much.

Test Program:

```
 public class RegEx1 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Str[] = {
        "PC|10000081|10000102|13513|10102026|LOC|ic",
        "PC|10000081|10000101|13512|10102025|LOC|zc",
    "NAME|10000042|10000084|13576|10101626|GENDER|cc",
    "NAME|10000042|10000084|13576|10101626|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10000042|10000084|13576|10101626|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|ic",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10001076|10001744|15106|10123669|GENDER|cc",
    "NAME|10001076|10001744|15106|10123669|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10001076|10001744|15106|10123669|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|ic",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10000061|10000086|13581|10101630|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10001075|10001743|15105|10123664|GENDER|ic",
    "NAME|10001075|10001743|15105|10123664|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10001075|10001743|15105|10123664|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10001077|10001745|15239|10123673|GENDER|cc",
    "NAME|10001077|10001745|15239|10123673|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10001077|10001745|15239|10123673|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10002165|10000102|10151364|10151363|GENDER|ic",
    "NAME|10002165|10003668|10151364|10151363|GENDER|za",
    "NAME|10002165|10003668|10151364|10151363|GENDER|zc",
    "NAME|10002167|10003670|10151368|10151367|GENDER|cc",
"NAME|10002167|10003670|10151368|10151367|GENDER|zb"    };

    for (String s : Str){
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s.matches("^NAME\\|10002167\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|*$"));
    }



   }
 }
```

For above program I get all input values as matches, actually it should match only strings where first column = "NAME" and 2nd column is 10002167.

**Update : Thanks to @Aviram Segal. After correcting regex it works in Java test program but not in HBase scan filter.**

Comment: What is the problem? What's the output?

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. Returns all rows. It works only when first regex values is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgot to escape one `|` character so it is treated as an `OR`, also you can use `[|]` instead of `\\|`, personally I like that style better.

Yours: `^NAME\\|.*\\|10000101|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*$`

Fixed: `^NAME\\|.*\\|10000101\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*$`

---

Yours: `System.out.println(s.matches("^NAME\\|10002167|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|*$"));`

Fixed: `System.out.println(s.matches("^NAME\\|10002167\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|*$"));`

Comment: What's wrong with this RegEx, this should match to all rows, but it doesn't match. System.out.println(s.matches("^\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|*$"));

Comment: You are missing `.*` (or `NAME`) before the first `\\|`, the regex you provided assumes the line starts with `|`

Comment: Duhhh. I thought I don't have to escape that one as it is matched with digits. It's working in test program. But doesn't work with HBase scan filter.

Comment: Adding .* corrected it. Thanks. But it still doesn't work in HBase scan filter. Hbase scan is still returning all rows.

Comment: It's working on HBase too now. I changed \\| to [|] and it's working on HBase now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`.` represent any character hence the issue. Try using `\w` for word characters in place of `.`.

Comment: The expressions he gave is matching just fine

Comment: `String regex = "^NAME\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*\\|.*$";
System.out.println("NAME|10000081|10000102|13513|10102026|GENDER|ID".matches(regex));` is true

Comment: @Reko: Did this help fixing your issue?

Comment: @YogendraSingh which suggestion? Aviram didn't suggest anything different. I am actually using that Regex.